# How to connect to `tcp://192.168.202.112:11053` by command line?

Tags: tcp, telnet

```
tcp://192.168.202.112:11053
```

I've ensured the service is on,but when `telnet 192.168.202.112 11053`,connection fails,why?

Comment: Are you sure it's not firewalled off?  The service can be on but no packets may actually be delivered.

Comment: just pointing out, there is no such thing as tcp:// and it doesn't even look like there is such a thing as telnet:// but your command would work. if ..

Comment: telnet listen on port 23, if you have not configured it to listen on 11053.

Answer (score 5):

Use `netcat` for arbitrary TCP and UDP connections. It is dedicated for this purpose. It can also listen on a port.

```
nc -v 192.168.202.112 11053
```

**Windows**

Netcat implementation for Windows: https://nmap.org/ncat/

**Note**

`Netcat` can run as a server:

```
nc -l <port-number>
```

This is helpful for testing connectivity, e.g. to check if firewall rule is applied.

Answer (score 4):

If that address was listening, and you had a path to it, your command `telnet 192.168.202.112 11053` would connect just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect from the local machine (where this service is running) to this port - if that works you have a firewall "problem"